Manga where the main character lives in a futuristic world, but has memories of ancient martial artists
The main character lives in a futuristic world that uses martial arts. He ends up getting memories from a martial artist from the past and learning the way they trained,
Apparently martial arts from that time are rare and expensive since it was the golden age of martial arts or whatever.
The memories he got were from a clan in which the person from the memories becomes the patriarch. He becomes super-strong by following the training in his memories and learns how to forge. He also get more memories from a different clan.
One of the things I remember is that he put ants that bite at the slightest movement in gloves and wore them to train his hands.
